# How to access qabstractlistmodel derived class object as a property of another class from qml?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qabstractlistmodel, qqmlengine

Iam designing a qml page which consists of 3 lists. I want the data to be displayed in these lists as model from cpp. Can i have all these 3 models as properties from a single class.

I have a class derived from qabstractlistmodel to use as model. I want this model as a property from another class which is bind to qml using qqmlcontextproperty.

ie. I could be able to access this model as a property.

```
class ToDoModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    ...
}

class HelperClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(ToDoModel todoModel READ todoModel CONSTANT)
public:
    explicit HelperClass(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    ToDoModel* todoModel() const;

signals:

public slots:

private:
    ToDoModel *_todoModel;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
HelperClass helperClass;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty(QStringLiteral("helperClass"), &helperClass);
...
}
```

It shows the error :

`Unable to handle unregistered datatype 'ToDoModel' for property 'HelperClass::todoModel'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A QObject, like the QAbstractListModel, is not copied, so in that case you must return the pointer. So in general if T is a QObject then if you expose it as a property it must be `Q_Property(T* name ...)`.

So in your case it changes to:

```
class HelperClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(ToDoModel* todoModel READ todoModel CONSTANT)
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [friend class](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/friend-class-function-cpp/) to allow access to private and protected members of other class

Comment: Actually i could pass that object to qml. but it shows 
```Unable to handle unregistered datatype 'ToDoModel' for property 'HelperClass::todoModel'```